# DocuSign Java client with Wildfly 10

Tags: docusignapi

I'm wondering whether anyone had an exprecience in deploying the DocuSign Java Client on WildFly 10?
DocuSign jvaa SDK depends on Jersey 1.19, while the wildfly 10 supports RESTEasy out of the box > is it possible to disable RESTEasy ?
Or will it be safe to use the RESTEasy as an JAX-RS implementation (instead of the Jersey 1.19)?

Thank you.

Comment: I would assume Wildfly will still work if the deployable has Jersey jar in it. I would suggest to deploy the code first and report any issues here. I would assume that Wildfly would not throw any error if it finds Jersey jar in the classpath.

Comment: Thank you, for you response. The only possible variant I've found is to disable the subsystem "jax-rs" for this specific deployment unit since there was a conflict due to different versions of jrs311 ( Jersey 1.19 depends on version 1.1.1 while the wildfly module javax.ws.rs is bundled with version 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will answer by myself: excluding the wildfky subsystem "jax-rs" in jboss-deployment-structure.xml works fine:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">

  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
       <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
  </deployment>
....
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution!